# Pgagent install on windows

Tags: postgresql, pgagent

I've looked at the documentation online but i cant find the 'pgagent.sql' script anywhere on my system. These are the instructions i'm following [here](http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.4/pgagent-install.html). Can i download it from anywhere else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check http://www.pgadmin.org/download/pgagent.php and chechout a current version of pgAdmin3: http://www.pgadmin.org/docs/1.10/pgagent-install.html